# php переменная в атрибуте "href"

Tags: php

```
$link_value = the_field('external-link');
echo '<a rel="nofollow" href="'.$link_value.'" class="btn-custom">Click me</a>';
```

Почему это не работает?

Comment: Вторая строка кода - рабочая. Ищите ошибку в первой строке.

Comment: Откройте сгенерированный html и посмотрите что не так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте так : `echo "<a href='".$link_address."'>Link</a>";`, либо так : `echo "<a href='$link_address'>Link</a>";`Поиграйтесь с кавычками...

Comment: к сожалению это не помогло, переменная выводится перед тегом ссылки, но не в "href". в чем еще может быть дело?

Comment: @skit008, the_field - выводит, отображает что-то.. Поэтому, попробуйте заменить the_field на get_field, или нечто похожее. Откройте консольку, посмотрите на ошибки, может атм что-то будет

Comment: get_field  помогло, спасибо большое)